# First modal scroll hiding when second modal is closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

When using two modals, on close of second modal the scroll of the first modal is hiding. 
An example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YanickRochon/949p0u6c/) (This is not my code I just used it to show what my problem is ). 
 My First modal box code is here

```
`<div id="myModalFirst" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex='-1'>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      // custom divs here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

My Second modal box code is here

```
`<div id="myModalSecond" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex='-1'>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      // custom divs here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Is there any solution for this issue.

Comment: Why are you using timer? cos you can do a .fadein(timer) .fadeout(timer) at the end of your html.().fadein(1000) ? did you tryed, regards.

Comment: @headmax Oh sorry thats not my code I just found it on someones question I just used it to show what my problem is

Comment: can you tryed this example if is good for you, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing second modal, the first one are getting overflow-y:hidden somehow. Even if its set to auto actually.
You can try like this using css

```
#myModalFirst {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I left the timer cos we add already one, and just add at the end a .fadein(1000); come in with 1s delay.

```
$('#modalTrigger').on('click', function () {

    $('#modalBody').html($('#contentText').html()).fadein(1000);

});

$('#btnPrimaryModalAction').on('click', function () {
    $('#secondaryModal').modal('show'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modal scroll work when body tag have class="modal-open". In generally when you close your second modal the class has been remove from the body tag and first modal scroll was not work at that time. So, adding a class="modal-open" when second modal is close it should work properly.

```js
$("#myModalSecond").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
  }, 500);
})
```